Error: Simulation failed - Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown
I'm encountering an issue while working with a Rust smart contract for a PvP game. The smart contract is deployed on the devnet, and I'm trying to interact with it through web3 in my project.
Creating a new room works without any problems. However, when I attempt to join the room, I receive the following error:
Error: Simulation failed. 
Message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown. 
Logs: 
[
  "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]",
  "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success",
  "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]",
  "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success",
  "Program FMxCTUk5WUCjTn7ggMLficj1fbR.... invoke [1]",
  "Program FMxCTUk5WUCjTn7ggMLficj1fbR.... consumed 1287 of 199700 compute units",
  "Program FMxCTUk5WUCjTn7ggMLficj1fbR.... failed: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown"
]. 
Catch the `SendTransactionError` and call `getLogs()` on it for full details.
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (index.browser.esm.js:7581:13)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (index.browser.esm.js:7546:20)
    at async joinRoom (useGameContract.js:145:20)

Smart Contract Part:
use borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize};
use solana_program::{
    account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
    entrypoint,
    entrypoint::ProgramResult,
    program::invoke,
    program_error::ProgramError,
    pubkey::Pubkey,
    system_instruction,
    sysvar::{rent::Rent, Sysvar},
};

#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug)]
pub struct GameRoom {
    pub creator: Pubkey,
    pub staker: Pubkey,
    pub amount: u64,
    pub staked: bool,
    pub active: bool,
}

#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug)]
pub enum GameInstruction {
    CreateRoom { amount: u64 },
    JoinRoom,
    ResolveRoom { winner: Pubkey },
    LeaveRoom,
}

entrypoint!(process_instruction);

pub fn process_instruction(
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
    let instruction = GameInstruction::try_from_slice(instruction_data)?;

    match instruction {
        GameInstruction::CreateRoom { amount } => create_room(accounts, amount, program_id),
        GameInstruction::JoinRoom => join_room(accounts, program_id),
        GameInstruction::ResolveRoom { winner } => resolve_room(accounts, winner, program_id),
        GameInstruction::LeaveRoom => leave_room(accounts, program_id),
    }
}

fn join_room(accounts: &[AccountInfo], program_id: &Pubkey) -> ProgramResult {
    let account_info_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
    let staker = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    let room_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;

    if room_account.owner != program_id {
        return Err(ProgramError::IncorrectProgramId);
    }

    let mut room = GameRoom::try_from_slice(&room_account.data.borrow())?;
    if !room.active || room.staker != Pubkey::default() {
        return Err(ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData);
    }

    // Ensure the staker stakes the same amount as the creator
    if staker.lamports() < room.amount {
        return Err(ProgramError::InsufficientFunds);
    }

    room.staker = *staker.key;
    room.staked = true;
    room.serialize(&mut &mut room_account.data.borrow_mut()[..])?;

    invoke(
        &system_instruction::transfer(staker.key, room_account.key, room.amount),
        &[staker.clone(), room_account.clone()],
    )?;

    Ok(())
}


Web3 Part:
import { PublicKey, SystemProgram, Transaction, TransactionInstruction, Connection, Keypair } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { serialize } from "borsh";

const PROGRAM_ID = new PublicKey("FMxCTUk5WUCjTn7ggMLficj1fbR3...");

class JoinRoomInstruction {
    constructor() {
        this.instruction = 1;
    }
}

const INSTRUCTION_SCHEMA = new Map([
    [JoinRoomInstruction, { kind: "struct", fields: [["instruction", "u8"]] }],
]);

const serializeInstruction = (instruction) => {
    return Buffer.from(serialize(INSTRUCTION_SCHEMA, instruction));
};

const useGameContract = () => {
    const connection = new Connection("https://api.devnet.solana.com", "confirmed");
    const { publicKey, signTransaction } = useWallet();

    const joinRoom = async (roomId) => {
        if (publicKey) {
            const { blockhash } = await connection.getRecentBlockhash();
            

            const instruction = new TransactionInstruction({
                keys: [
                    { pubkey: publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: false },
                    { pubkey: new PublicKey(roomId), isSigner: false, isWritable: true },
                ],
                programId: PROGRAM_ID,
                data: serializeInstruction(new JoinRoomInstruction()),
            });
    

            const transaction = new Transaction().add(instruction);
            transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
            transaction.feePayer = publicKey;
    
            try {
                let signedTransaction = await signTransaction(transaction);
                console.log(signedTransaction.serialize());
                let txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(signedTransaction.serialize());
                console.log(txid);
                await connection.confirmTransaction(txid);
                return txid;
            } catch (error) {
                throw error;
            }
        } else {
            throw new Error("Wallet not connected");
        }
    };

    return { joinRoom };
};

export default useGameContract;

Any guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
This is createRoom part that working properly
    const createRoom = async (amount) => {
        if (publicKey) {
            const { blockhash } = await connection.getRecentBlockhash();
            const roomAccount = Keypair.generate();
            const lamports = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(1024);

            // Create room account instruction
            const createAccountInstruction = SystemProgram.createAccount({
                fromPubkey: publicKey,
                newAccountPubkey: roomAccount.publicKey,
                lamports,
                space: 1024,
                programId: PROGRAM_ID,
            });

            // Transfer staking amount instruction
            const transferInstruction = SystemProgram.transfer({
                fromPubkey: publicKey,
                toPubkey: roomAccount.publicKey,
                lamports: amount,
            });

            // Create room instruction
            const createRoomInstruction = new TransactionInstruction({
                keys: [
                    { pubkey: publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: false },
                    { pubkey: roomAccount.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true },
                ],
                programId: PROGRAM_ID,
                data: serializeInstruction(new CreateRoomInstruction(amount)),
            });

            // Build the transaction
            const transaction = new Transaction()
                .add(createAccountInstruction)
                .add(transferInstruction)
                .add(createRoomInstruction);

            transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
            transaction.feePayer = publicKey;

            // Partial sign with the room account
            transaction.partialSign(roomAccount);

            // Sign with the user's wallet
            let signedTransaction = await signTransaction(transaction);
            signedTransaction.partialSign(roomAccount);

            // Send the transaction and confirm
            let txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(signedTransaction.serialize());
            await connection.confirmTransaction(txid);

            return roomAccount.publicKey.toString();
        } else {
            throw new Error("Wallet not connected");
        }
    };

